# Regex square bracket help

Tags: php, regex

I need to specify in a regular expression to match all positive and negative numbers. I want it to match only a single `-` at the start, but if its not present (i.e in a positive number) that should work too.

If I try:

```
^[-][0-9]+$
```

This matches only -100, -200, but not 200, 100, etc. How can I change it to match both 100, 200, -100, but not --100?

Comment: Why the downvote without a comment? What's wrong with this question?

Comment: Good resource for learning regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: @aib: It wasn't me but maybe because it can be answered by a simple Google search: https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=regex+optional+character

Comment: Or maybe it's a political thing, I just looked at the OP's profile...

Comment: You may use `^[+-]?[0-9]+$` since `+100` is also a valid number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `?` modifier (means zero or one). i.e. `-?` or `-{0,1}`.

Answer (score 4):

```
^-?[0-9]+$
```

You don't need a character class `[]` for one character. `?` means match zero or one time the previous character/group.